# Is pH found using negative log because the scientific notation of the number of hydrogen atoms in a solution is always negative?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, chemistry

I understand subtraction negates addition, and since log and exponents are basically addition and subtraction on steroids, then log must be the way to negate exponents. So from this rationale, is it fair to say that log is negative because the exponents are negative? That if it were any other quantities that involved whole numbers, then log would be positive?

For context, the equation for pH is:

$$[\text{H}^+][\text{OH}^-]=1×10^{-14} \text{ mol}^{2} \text{ dm}^{-6}$$

And if you know the number of hydronium ions present, then it can be found with the equation:
pH = - log(H+) 
, which is the equation referred to in the question.

Comment: I partly agree with your reasoning, according to the definition on wikipedia, it's correct - it also goes on there to explain that ph can actually be zero (1 mole per litre - the log of 1 is zero, and even -1 which would be 10 moles per litre, -log(10) = -1

Comment: log($10^{-14}$) = -14 for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under reasonable conditions, at any given moment, only a tiny fraction of water molecules are dissociated into the ${\rm H}^+$ and ${\rm OH}^{-}$ ions. Therefore, the [molar concentrations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration) of these ions are very small numbers, so their logarithms  are negative. The customary definition of pH takes this into account.

If we add acid to water, then ${\rm H}^+$ ions' concentration grows by orders of magnitude, but still there are way fewer ${\rm H}^+$ ions than water molecules, and the concentration of ${\rm H}^+$ ions still remains a small number. So the logarithm of ${\rm H}^+$ ions' concentration remains negative in the vast majority of situations, and the pH definition still works as intended, stripping the minus sign of the logarithm.